# Download 2 files Spring Batch Step

Tags: file, download, spring-batch

I am building a Spring Batch Job that has 2 steps for downloading 2 files. The file names are job parameters.

Please find below the steps configuration class (FileDownloader and FileDownloadTasklet are custom classes for the download logic):

```
@Autowired
 private FileDownloader fileDownloader;

 @Autowired
 private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

 @Bean
 public Step downloadFirstFileStep() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("downloadFirstFileStep")
       .tasklet(firstFileDownloadTasklet(null)).build();
 }

 @Bean
 @StepScope
 public FileDownloadTasklet firstFileDownloadTasklet(
     @Value("#{jobParameters['firstFile']}") String fileName) {
   return new FileDownloadTasklet(fileDownloader, fileName);
 }

 @Bean
 public Step downloadSecondFileStep() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("downloadSecondFileStep")
       .tasklet(secondFileDownloadTasklet(null)).build();
 }

 @Bean
 @StepScope
 public FileDownloadTasklet secondFileDownloadTasklet(
     @Value("#{jobParameters['secondFile']}") String fileName) {
   return new FileDownloadTasklet(fileDownloader, fileName);
 }
```

I'm feeling I'm not doing the right thing by duplicating the Step beans since the only difference is the actual name of the file to be downloaded. 
Can you please give me a hint on how can I do it without duplicating the beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can do this in better way using a partitioner. Currently you are downloading 2 files and future you might want to download more number of files.

```
@Bean(name = "partitionerJob")
public Job partitionerJob()  {
    return jobs.get("partitioningJob")
      .start(partitionStep())
      .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Step partitionStep()  {
    return steps.get("partitionStep")
      .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner())
      .step(downloadFirstFileStep())
      .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
      .build();
}

 @Bean
 public Step downloadFirstFileStep() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("downloadFirstFileStep")
       .tasklet(firstFileDownloadTasklet(null)).build();
 }

 @Bean
 @StepScope
 public FileDownloadTasklet firstFileDownloadTasklet(
     @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String fileName) {
   return new FileDownloadTasklet(fileDownloader, fileName);
 }

@Bean
public YourPartitioner partitioner() {
    return new YourPartitioner();
}



public class YourPartitioner implements Partitioner {

     @Value("#{jobParameters['fileNames']}") //Pass Comma separated file names as argument
     protected String fileNames;

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
        int i = 0, k = 1;
        for (String resource : fileNames.split(",") {
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            context.putString("fileName", resource); //This will be fetched as argument to the step job from JobExecutionContext
            map.put("PARTITION_KEY " + i, context);
            i++;
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sushil! you got me unstuck :)